# Failing to load Tidyverse R Packages

Tags: r, tidyverse, rstudio

I cannot load Tidyverse and Glimma. Below is the code I tried for loading (using tidyverse as an example)

```
library(tidyverse)
```

This is the error message I get:

```
    Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in namespaceExport(ns, exports):
     undefined exports: BROWSE, DELETE, GET, HEAD, PATCH, POST, PUT, RETRY, Token, Token1.0, Token2.0, TokenServiceAccount, VERB, accept, accept_json, accept_xml, add_headers, authenticate, build_url, cache_info, config, content, content_type, content_type_json, content_type_xml, cookies, curl_docs, get_callback, guess_media, handle, handle_find, handle_reset, has_content, headers, hmac_sha1, http_condition, http_date, http_error, http_status, http_type, httr_dr, httr_options, init_oauth1.0, init_oauth2.0, insensitive, message_for_status, modify_url, oauth1.0_token, oauth2.0_access_token, oauth2.0_authorize_url, oauth2.0_token, oauth_app, oauth_callback, oauth_endpoint, oauth_endpoints, oauth_exchanger, oauth_header, oauth_listener, oauth_service_token, oauth_signature, parse_http_date, parse_media, parse_url, parsed_content, progress, rerequest, reset_config, revoke_all, set_callback, set_config, set_
    In addition: Warning messages:
    1: package ‘tidyverse’ was built under R version 4.1.3 
    2: S3 methods ‘$.insensitive’, ‘[.insensitive’, ‘[[.insensitive’, ‘as.character.form_file’, ‘as.character.response’, ‘as_field.default’, ‘as_field.logical’, ‘as_field.numeric’, ‘c.request’, ‘cookies.handle’, ‘cookies.response’, ‘headers.response’, ‘http_error.character’, ‘http_error.integer’, ‘http_error.response’, ‘print.cache_info’, ‘print.handle’, ‘print.oauth_app’, ‘print.oauth_endpoint’, ‘print.opts_list’, ‘print.request’, ‘print.response’, ‘status_code.numeric’, ‘status_code.response’ were declared in NAMESPACE but not found
```

This is the R version information:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Australia.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Australia.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Australia.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                       LC_TIME=English_Australia.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.1.1 tools_4.1.1
```

I tried the following:

1. reinstalled the package, adding dependencies = T

```
remove.packages("tidyverse")

install.packages("tidyverse", dependencies = TRUE)
```

2. Downloading RTools

Comment: What version of R do you have?

Comment: Hi Phil, my R version is 4.1.1. I am also attaching the sessioninfo() output

Comment: As per the message, you need to update your version of R.

Comment: Hi, I updated my R to 4.2.1 and that fixed the problem. Many thanks Phil!